# Run Android emulator and Developing IDE on separate Virtual Machines

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, android, eclipse

I try to setup development enviroment for Android apps. Before all my development was performed in ubuntu running with virtual box. I have install adt plugin for my eclipse and download Android SDK in this Ubuntu, but find out that android emulator didn't start in virtualbox VM. At present moment I didn't find any clear tutorial hwo to run anroid emulator in eclipse under VirtualVM, instead I find a lot of notice about very slow working of emulator in VirtualVM and recomendation to use Android x86 as Virtual VM for debugging. I wonder if there is a way to start two Virtual VM (Ubuntu with IDE and Android x86 for debugging) and connect them somehow to allow debug code from Ubuntu in Android x86?

P.S. I also will be thankful for clear tutorial how to run emulator in eclipse in VirtualVM.

Comment: What are the specs of your VM? How much RAM did you give it, and how many virtual processors? 2 separate virtual machines sounds like overkill, lets try to figure out the root cause of the problem.

Comment: At ubuntu now I set 2 processors and 4Gb of RAM. Total in my system 8Gb ram and 4 processors (Intel i3), as I read for android x86 512Mb + 1 processor is enought. Root of the problem I already write - android emulator didn`t start in VM (Ubuntu). I find out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971621/android-emulator-not-starting-in-a-virtualbox-ubuntu-instance on this problem.